# Referencing public files when editing nodes

Tags: nodes, media, files

Right now when I want to include an image into a node I have to specify a path like

```
<img src="/sites/example.com/files/profile.jpg" />
```

The problem is if the **Public file system path** configuration setting changes, all the links will get broken.

Is there any way to say something like

```
<img src="public://profile.jpg" />
```

to embed images?

Comment: how are you 'embedding' the images? in an editor?

Comment: @Geoff yes, when editing the body of a node.

Comment: doing it manually? or using a module like Insert ? - you really shouldn't be changing the file system that much, that often, but a simple sql statement could rectify any adjustments you need to do, that's usually how its handled